# Remove DataGridView On clicking on it

Tags: vb.net

I'm using following code to add datagrid view to my form manually but the problem is that when i want to add datagridview click event it gives an error

```
Dim DgvUs(10) As DataGridView

Public Sub Add(ByVal dgNum As Integer)
    DgvUs(dgNum) = New DataGridView
    Dim cl1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    cl1.HeaderText = "cA"
    cl1.Name = "cA"
    cl1.Width = 90
    Dim cl2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    cl2.HeaderText = "cB"
    cl2.Name = "cB"
    cl2.Width = 90

    DgvUs(dgNum).Columns.Add(cl1)
    DgvUs(dgNum).Columns.Add(cl2)
    DgvUs(dgNum).RowHeadersVisible = False
    DgvUs(dgNum).Width = 180
    DgvUs(dgNum).ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
    DgvUs(dgNum).Dock = DockStyle.Left
    DgvUs(dgNum).Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    DgvUs(dgNum).Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    DgvUs(dgNum).AllowUserToAddRows = False


    panelN.Controls.Add(DgvUs(dgNum))

End Sub
```

Adding datagridview works fine but
Click Event Gives ana error

```
 Private Sub DGV_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) _
 Handles DgvUs(1).MouseClick
    'Click Event
 End Sub
```

('.' expected)

Any Suggestion / Solution Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you can add events at runtime (this is how you add them at design time). You have to use a code on these lines:

```
AddHandler DgvUs(dgNum).MouseClick, AddressOf DGV_MouseClick
```

And convert the method into:

```
Private Sub DGV_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

    Dim curDGV As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView) 'This is the DataGridView you are currently clicking on

End Sub
```